# Can't pass a variable to ajax url

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to pass an id to my controller with ajax.

I want to use the id var in the ajax URL but it's not working.

*where I'm setting the ID*

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control traite" data-id="{{ $conversation->id }}"></td>
```

*the jquery function*

```
$(document).on('click', '.traite', function() {
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
var id = $(this).data('id');
$.ajax({
    url: "{{ route('traitements.change_traite_conversation', " + id + ") }}",
    type:"POST",
    dataType:"JSON",
    data: {
        "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
        "id" : id
    },
    success: function() {
        console.log("Updated");
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
    console.log(xhr.responseText); // this line will save you tons of hours while debugging
    // do something here because of error
    }
});

console.log("Error");
});
```

*web.php*

```
Route::post('conversation/{id}/traiter', 'TraitementController@change_traite_conversation')->name('traitements.change_traite_conversation');
```

*the error I get*

```
{
"message": "Undefined variable: id",
[...]
}
```

I don't understand why I can't pass my ID to the ajax URL, I can normally console.log it and it's working !

Comment: Everything between your mustache (`{{ ... }}`) is parsed by Laravel, so you can't append your id (which is part of your js code) in the middle of the mustache syntax. You'll have to find another way to get your id in there

Comment: Nice to know ! Thank you, I'm now trying to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Html**. pass it in data attribute instead of `id` you may pass `url` don't you?

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control traite" data-url="{{ route('traitements.change_traite_conversation', $conversation->id) }}"></td>
```

**Jquery**, get that data-url in jquery.

```
$(document).on('click', '.traite', function() {
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
var url = $(this).data('url');

$.ajax({
    url: url,
```

Otherwise, you can directly pass php variable but in your case you need to dynamic so I think it'll not work.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "{{ route('traitements.change_traite_conversation', $conversation->id) }}",
```

Comment: Now laravel can't find the conversation variable, I think it's because I'm using a foreach for this one

Comment: If you can find dynamic `data-id`  so you can also generate dynamic `data-url` don't you? as I show you in my answer you can generate dynamic url and pass it to the url of ajax call. Thank you,

Comment: I don't know why but the conversation variable isn't working : `"message": "Undefined variable: Conversation",` EDIT : probably my fault, trying to resolve it EDIT2: Working, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should add `fullurl` `attr` in html then get using `javascript` or `jQuery`.

In **HTML** file :

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control traite" data-id="{{ $conversation->id }}" data-fullurl="{{ route('traitements.change_traite_conversation', $conversation->id) }}"></td>
```

In **Javascript/JQuery** script:

```
$(document).on('click', '.traite', function() {
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
var URL = $(this).data('fullurl');
var id = $(this).data('id');
$.ajax({
    url: URL,
    type:"POST",
    dataType:"JSON",
    data: {
        "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
        "id" : id
    },
    success: function() {
        console.log("Updated");
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
    console.log(xhr.responseText); // this line will save you tons of hours while debugging
    // do something here because of error
    }
});

console.log("Error");
});
```

Comment: Laravel can't find the conversation variable now

Comment: Check you whether `$conversation` is passing to your view or not from controller.

Comment: nothing, the 2 are the same at the end, but he doesn't saw yours i think

Comment: @Laravel I had not seen you answer. About difference I had explained about passing `fullurl` attr to add in html and placed @Petoux full code that why he can copy and use that directly.

Comment: @Petoux That's great to know.